# How can flammable gas become non-flammable when mixed with another gas with comparable percentage?

Tags: combustion

For example, R-410a is a 50-50 mixture of R-32 and R-125. R-32 is flammable (class A2L) and R-410a is not flammable (class A1).

Flammability of refrigerant is mainly a concern when it is leaked since there is no oxidizer when it is not leaked. But when leaked, it become gas in air. In the case of R-410a, it will become gas of 50-50 R-32 and R-125, which then diffuse and  mix with air. Since air in the room is far more than the leaked R-410a, the oxygen molecules will surround (i.e. collide with at some rate) R-32 molecules just like when pure R-32 is leaked. Then how does R-125 make R-32 inflammable under the same condition?

The only way that I can imagine for this to happen is that R-125 and R-32 molecules combine to form some aggregation of a couple of molecules in air which prevent the reaction with oxygen to happen - do they? What are other ways that can make this (i.e. the title) happen.

Comment: Aggregation is not a part of the picture, nor is it needed. Think of it this way: will the air with _just a few molecules_ of R-32 be flammable?

Comment: For many compounds, there are tables about lower and the upper _experimentally determined_ [flammability limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flammability_limit).  That is, what is the minimal concentration / maximal concentration of a compound in air (typically) or a specific gas to be susceptible to burn / to oxidize / to explode.  It is not a simple scalar property you may add by mixing gas A and B to obtain a flammability.

Comment: There are many compounds that suppress burning even in low concentrations. The mechanism is that they interfere with the reactions that propagate combustion (often by terminating some radical process). Combustion is a bulk process so the presence of small amounts of molecules that interfere can stop the process happening.

Comment: Who else saw the title edit and cracked up?

Comment: I think there must be distinction between flammability and explosive limits. The former is about  composition of potential fuel in contact with air, while the latter about its gaseous mixture with air.   Like how much of N2 can be in CH4 to be still able to  light it up, versus how much of given CH4/N2 mixture, mixed with air,  can explode.